# How to pause Shaka player after it is loaded?

Tags: html5-video, shaka

Is there any configuration that I can pass so that the Shaka Player pauses itself at certain duration/point in the video? , for e.g. I want to pause player on 300 seconds.

One way is to change `playRangeEnd` configuration, but that messes the user experience
Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TheModMaker on https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/2510 ,
This is related to the native video element, not the Shaka.

`timeupdate` event can be used to achieve this, like,

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  if (video.currentTime >= 300)
    video.pause();
});
```

`timeupdate` event is fired when the video's currentTime is updated.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event

Comment: your statement "This is related to the native video element, not the Shaka." saved my time. Thanks.